# Floating blocks in Gutenberg editor

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to develop a block that can align left/right in a floating way like do the blocks core/image, core/audio, ... I mean that the UI of Gutenberg adapts to that position and you can have a paragraph arround the aligned/floating block. All of it very natural/native.

I have been contrasting the HTML generated by their blocks and the source code.

In the first example, there is a paragraph with class wp-block among others. That's the normal composition. The most external element of your block gets all the Gutenberg classes.

In the second example, there is a div with only the class wp-block and the data-align attribute. That's the behaviuor that I am tring to replicate.

**HTML structure created by the core/audio block:**

[image: HTML structure created by the core/audio block]

**How is shown the core/audio block:**

[image: How is shown the core/audio block]

**Here is my code and the problem visually explained.**

The code is very similar to https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/audio/edit.js

```
const { useBlockProps } = wp.blockEditor;
const { BlockAlignmentToolbar, BlockControls } = wp.editor;
const { Component } = wp.element;

wp.blocks.registerBlockType( 'melange/test-aligns', {
    category:    'melangeLayout',
    title:       'Test aligns',
    description: '',
    attributes: {
        align: { type: 'string',  default: null, },
    },
//  supports: { align: true },
    edit: function({attributes, setAttributes}) {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps();
        return <>
            <BlockControls>
                <BlockAlignmentToolbar
                    value    = { attributes.align }
                    onChange = { align => setAttributes({align}) }
                />
            </BlockControls>
            <p {...blockProps}>Hello world!</p>
        </>
    },
    getEditWrapperProps(attrs) {
        return { ...attrs, 'data-align': attrs.align };
    },
    save: function() {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
        return <p {...blockProps}>Hello world!</p>;
    },
});
```

**My problem is** that the floating block has two blockcontrols depending where is the mouse hovering.

**And the reason is** the created divs doesn´t have the same structure as they have in core blocks. I don´t know why, my block gets wrapped by an extra div which is not needed, in fact duplicates the id.

[image: Dobule div with the same id attribute]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockType( 'melange/test-aligns', {
    apiVersion: 2,
    ...
});
```

As seen in https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/

But, I don´t know why, they don´t need it in Gutenberg source code.